# Any Way To Create Database Relationship Diagram In Visual Studio

Tags: sql, database, entity

I want to view my database's relation diagram but I don't see an option to do so.
I am using code first method to generate my database.
Please do not suggest Entity Framework Power Tools, they do not work for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you cannot create, view database diagram via server explorer.

I recommend you download and install [SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)
It has an express edition that is free to use.

You can use it to connect to your database, create a diagram and view it.
If you are not sure how to do it check this out -> [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18TC7-8kLSc)

If you want to edit your entities not only view them you can do so in the Model Browser Window in VS

Good Luck